# Laravel join two tables with where that compares two date time columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables that I want to run joint query on using the value of two date time columns, I have products table and sync_status tables, I want to return all products with updated_at date time greater than synced_at date time.

```
DB::table('products')
    ->join('sync_statuses', function ($join) {
        $join->on('products.product_number', '=', 'sync_statuses.product_number')
            ->where('products.updated_at', '>', 'sync_statuses.synced_at')
            ->whereNull('products.deleted_at');
    })
    ->select('products.product_number');
```

This SQL represents what I am trying to achieve using Eloquent:

```
SELECT products.product_number
FROM products
JOIN push_statuses
ON products.product_number = statuses.product_number
AND (
  statuses.synced_at IS NULL
  OR products.updated_at > statuses.synced_at
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `on()` instead of `where()` to compare columns:

```
->on('products.updated_at', '>', 'sync_statuses.synced_at')
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
DB::table('products')
        ->join('statuses', function ($join) {
            $join->on('products.product_number', '=', 'statuses.product_number')
                ->where(DB::raw('products.updated_at'), '>=', DB::raw('statuses.synced_at'))
                ->whereNull('products.deleted_at');

        })->select('products.product_number');
```

I needed to use `DB::raw('products.updated_at')` to reference each date time column in the where() clause.